# How to change the layout of the d3js chart?

Tags: javascript, json, layout, d3.js

I recently started using d3js and I am currently trying to figure out how to use transitions.

I got the [TreeMap example](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/ex/treemap.html) working with my own json file.

My question is: How can I change the layout with a transition from the `treemap` to a `tree`?

My json data looks like this:

```
{"name": "OS",
 "children": [
   {"name": "Linux x64",
    "children": [
      {"name": "Linux (amd64)", "size": 58154},
      {"name": "Linux (ia64)", "size": 3}
    ]
   },
   {"name": "Linux x86",
    "children": [
      {"name": "Linux (i386)", "size": 12269}
    ]
   },
   {"name": "Mac OS x64",
    "children": [
      {"name": "Mac OS X (x86_64)", "size": 53118}
    ]
   },
   {"name": "Mac OS x86",
    "children": [
      {"name": "Mac OS X (i386)", "size": 409}
    ]
   },
   {"name": "SunOS x64",
    "children": [
      {"name": "SunOS (amd64)", "size": 3}
    ]
   },
   {"name": "SunOS x86",
    "children": [
      {"name": "SunOS (x86)", "size": 8}
    ]
   },
   {"name": "Windows x64",
    "children": [
      {"name": "Windows 2003 (amd64)", "size": 32},
      {"name": "Windows 7 (amd64)", "size": 25492},
      {"name": "Windows 8 (amd64)", "size": 19},
      {"name": "Windows NT (unknown) (amd64)", "size": 76},
      {"name": "Windows Server 2008 (amd64)", "size": 349},
      {"name": "Windows Server 2008 R2 (amd64)", "size": 428},
      {"name": "Windows Vista (amd64)", "size": 1337},
      {"name": "Windows XP (amd64)", "size": 1284}
    ]
   },
   {"name": "Windows x86",
    "children": [
      {"name": "Windows 2000 (x86)", "size": 147},
      {"name": "Windows 2003 (x86)", "size": 390},
      {"name": "Windows 7 (x86)", "size": 17933},
      {"name": "Windows 8 (x86)", "size": 10},
      {"name": "Windows 95 (x86)", "size": 2},
      {"name": "Windows NT (unknown) (x86)", "size": 13},
      {"name": "Windows Server 2008 (x86)", "size": 19},
      {"name": "Windows Server 2008 R2 (x86)", "size": 43},
      {"name": "Windows Vista (x86)", "size": 4815},
      {"name": "Windows XP (x86)", "size": 34545}
    ]
   }
 ]
}
```

I didn't really change the example code, but I can post it, if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't make transition from a TreeMap to Tree... Transition change styles or attributes but you cant make a transition from one layout to another.

**For dummies: transitions is like change apple's color from red to green or to change it's size, but you can't change an apple by an orange.**

Comment: Ok, maybe I misused the term "transition". My question aims at somehow "morphing" a treemap into a tree, i.e. changing the layout on the fly. Is that possible?

Comment: @Baz you can create a new layout over the old one, and make a jquery fade or something if you want to give it some effect, but you can't  "morph, transition or whatever" from one layout to another.

Comment: Then how does [this](http://bl.ocks.org/1256572) example work? I tried understanding the code, but I'm fairly new to javascript and d3.js.

Comment: these are a mix between transition applied to a single layout and transitions between layouts coding by hand (custom transition) transforming each SVG layout to something similar to the next layout and applying a fade effect, and only works for those layouts (from layout a to layout b), there are no standard transition between layouts.

Comment: Well, I guess that's the answer then.